# Rsync mirror specific Ubuntu distributions

Tags: rsync, mirrors, apt-mirror

How do I mirror specific Ubuntu distributions using Rsync?

For example, using apt-mirror I would have the following lines so I would only have the package for 12.04

```
deb (mirror address)/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb (mirror address)/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb (mirror address)/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb-amd64 (mirror address)/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 (mirror address)/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 (mirror address)/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb-i386 (mirror address)/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 (mirror address)/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 (mirror address)/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: Wanted to use RSYNC so I could use its native bandwidth throttle and the new feature in v3.1.0 that allows view of total progress (--info=progress2)

Answer (score 0):

apt-mirror does the same task you are trying to achieve: it downloads new packages from repository, and delete old ones, so rsync will probably not do better than that.